# download android .apk in background and install silently in background

Tags: android, download, background

I am making a kiosk application.

I want to download android .apk in the background from my website and install silently in the background.

Is there any way to do so? I want this functionality on a non-rooted device.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was possible. Seems like a great way for hackers to silently install applications on someones phone.

Comment: its not possible on non rooted device. Its only possible if your app has greater access like root or if its a system app

Comment: Its seems you want to try some hacking. The root access was designed to block such access.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible on a non-rooted device.